# Tabular - DAX - Filter Value for current logged on User

Tags: filter, ssas, tabular, dax

i have the following Scenario:

I have a Power View Report that Shows certain Values for Employee's based on the Projects they have worked in.

Now, until the Report is filtered for the Currently logged in User, the User openning the Report will see everything about the Projects they have worked on, including the engagement of others in the Projects.

What i Need is to have it all only showing, therefore filtered, after the Currently logged in User.

I have a Employee Table that has columns like: Employee Name and Login,

and i thought i could create something like a Calculated column which would produce the Currently logged on user, and that would then be used by me later in the Report, where i would simply open the Employee Table and Filter where Employee is Logged on User.

Does anyone have any Idea about how this is to be accomplished ?

or, does anyone know a better way ?

Comment: What is the data source for Power View?  How is it deployed?

Comment: If you are using Power Pivot as your source, there is no built in functionality for this and you will have to roll your own.  If you are using Tabular SSAS, you can use [roles and filters to control the data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479759.aspx)